# Gnuplot linecolor by palette, but key not

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have the following `gnuplot` script.

```
set terminal epslatex standalone size 8cm, 4cm
set output "test.tex"
set palette defined ( 0 "black", 1 "red" )

plot \
    "a.dat" using 1:2:3 linecolor palette z pointtype 9 title "a" , \
    "b.dat" using 1:2:3 linecolor palette z pointtype 5 title "b" , \
    "c.dat" using 1:2:3 linecolor palette z pointtype 7 title "c"
```

And the following sample datasets

`a.dat`:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
3 0 3
4 0 4
```

`b.dat`

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
```

`c.dat`

```
0 2 0
1 2 1
2 2 2
```

This gives me the following

[image: Sample picture]

My problem with this example is that the keys in the legend, all get the color of the last datapoint of the respective input file. Basically, what I want all of the symbols in the key to be of the same color. How can I achieve that?

I am using gnuplot 4.6.2 (and 4.6.5). I am looking for a general solution. I.e., I am not really looking for a solution where I have to alter the data file (because it is updated on a regular basis).

Comment: @Christoph In my full use case, "a" is square and "c" triangle. The reason to use uniform color, is because it is ugly otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option which comes into my mind is to use a separate plot expression for each title where you specify the color you actually want in the key:

```
set terminal epslatex standalone size 8cm, 4cm
set output "test.tex"
set palette defined ( 0 "black", 1 "red" )

set key samplen 1
set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1

plot \
    "a.dat" using 1:2:3 palette pt 9 notitle, "" using 1:(NaN) lc rgb 'black' pt 9 title 'a', \
    "b.dat" using 1:2:3 palette pt 5 notitle, "" using 1:(NaN) lc rgb 'black' pt 5 title 'b', \
    "c.dat" using 1:2:3 palette pt 7 notitle, "" using 1:(NaN) lc rgb 'black' pt 7 title 'c'

set output 
system('latex test && dvips test && ps2pdf test.ps')
```

[image]

Alternatively you could also manually set three labels with the `point` option, but that might require more fiddling to get the position and alignments correct.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to do it like this.